# vuejs Navbar links not workig

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vue-router

My vuejs application has a navigation bar and its code as bellow.
The problem is navigation bar display with its color but no links are available at the navigation bar .also console display a error like this [click here to view the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9ClI.png) . when I searched through the stackoverflow  i found that some answers related to my problem and on was changing **auth: ''** to  **auth: {}** . But it dosent also worked .So could any please help me to fix this.Thanks

```
<template>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expan-lg navbar-dar bg-primary rounded">
<button class="navbar-toggler"
type="button"
data-toggle="collapse"
data-target="#navbar1"
aria-controls="navbar1"
aria-expanded="false"
aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-md-center"    id="navbar1">
  <ul class="navbar-ul">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <router-link class="nav-link" to="/home">Home</router-link>
    </li>
     <li v-if="auth == ''" class="nav-item">
      <router-link class="nav-link" to="/login">Login</router-link>
    </li>
     <li v-if="auth == ''" class="nav-item">
      <router-link class="nav-link" to="/register">Register</router-link>
    </li>
     <li v-if="auth == 'loggedin'" class="nav-item">
      <router-link class="nav-link" to="/profile">Profile</router-link>
    </li>
     <li v-if="auth == 'loggedin'" class="nav-item">
      <router-link class="nav-link" to="/logout">Logout</router-link>
    </li>
  </ul>

 </div>
 </nav>
 </template>

<script>
import EventBus from './EventBus'
export default {
 data () {
return {
  auth: '',
  user: ''
  }
 },
 methods: {
 logout () {
  localStorage.removeItem('usertoken')
 }
},
mounted () {
EventBus.$on('logged-in', status => {
  this.auth = status
 })
}
}
```

This is the index.js of Router folder

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Home from '@/components/Home'
import Login from '@/components/Login'
import Register from '@/components/Register'
import Profile from '@/components/Profile'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Home',
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: '/login',
      name: 'Login',
      component: Login
    },
    {
      path: '/register',
      name: 'Register',
      component: Register
    },
    {
      path: '/profile',
      name: 'Profile',
      component: Profile
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: It looks like your `RouterLink` component is missing a `prop` named "to" — can you include the component code here too?

Comment: @lto Pizarro Could you please check the updated code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `to` in your last link. Replace the `href` with `to` and you error should dissappear.

```html
     <li v-if="auth == 'loggedin'" class="nav-item">
      <router-link class="nav-link" to="">Logout</router-link>
    </li>
```

The error about `name` on undefined should be gone too. This is probably because it cannot find the a route with the key `undefined` as defined by the `router-link`

If this doesn't solve it, you may need to post more code.

Comment: I have chaged href to ,to but it also dosent working.

Comment: this is the code of App.vue                                                                                                <template>
      <div id="app">
    <navbar></navbar>
       <router-view/>
       </div>
     </template>

      <script>
           import Navbar from './components/Navbar'

        export default {
         name: 'App',
         components: {
           'Navbar': Navbar
       }
    }
      </script>

Comment: I have pointed all to attributes but still its not working. Please help

Comment: have a look at https://jsfiddle.net/13Lz2xfq/  replacing `href` with `to` fixes the `missing required prop: "to"` error